# Observer pattern usage in syntax tree parsing

Tags: parsing, design-patterns, syntax, tree, observer-pattern

I have detailed the specifications of the problem for reasons that will become clear after I ask my question, at the end. The program I am building is a parser in Java for a language with the following syntax (although this is not very relevant to the question):

```
<expr> ::= [<op> <expr> <expr>] | <symbol> | <value>
<symbol> ::= [a-zA-Z]+
<value> ::= [0-9]+
<op> ::= '+' | '*' | '==' | ‘<’
<assignment> ::= [= <symbol> <expr>]
<prog> ::= <assignment> |
           [; <prog> <prog>] |
           [if <expr> <prog> <prog>] |
           [for <assignment> <expr> <assignment> <prog>] |
           [assert <expr>] |
           [return <expr>]`
```

This is an example of code in said language:

```
[; [= x 0] [; [if [== x 5] [= x 7] [= x [+ x 1]]] [return x]]]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
x = 0;
if (x == 5)
    x = 7;
else
    x = x + 1;
return x;`
```

The code is guaranteed to be give in correct syntax; incorrectness of the given code is defined only by having:
a) An used variable (symbol) not previously declared (by declared meaning assigned something to it), even if the variable is used in a branch of an if or some other place that is never reached in the execution of the program;
b) Having a "return" instruction on each path the program could take, meaning the program cannot end without returning on any execution path it may take.
The requirements are that the program should parse the code.

**My parser must:**
a) Check for said correctness;
b) Parse the code and compute what is the returned value.

**My take on this is:**
1) Parse the code given into a tree of instructions and expressions;
2) Check for correctness by traversing the tree and seeing if a variable was declared in an upper scope before it was used;
3) Check for correctness by traversing the tree and seeing if any execution branch ends in a "return" instruction;
4) If all previous conditions hold, evaluate the returned value of the code by traversing the tree and remembering the value of all the variables in a HashMap or some other storage.

Now, **my problem** is that I must implement the parser using the **Visitor** and **Observer** design patterns. This is a key requirement for the project. I am fairly new to design patterns and only have a basic grasp about these two.

**My question is: where should/can I use the Observer design patter in my parser?**

It makes sense to use a Visitor to visit the nodes of the tree for steps 2, 3 and 4. I cannot figure out where I must use the Observer pattern, though.
Is there any place I can use it in my implementation? From my understanding, the Observer pattern takes care of data that can be read and modified by many "observers", the central idea being that an object modifying the data will announce the other objects that may be affected by the modification.

The main data being modified in my program is the **tree** and the **HashMap** in which I store the values for the variables. Both of there are accessed in a linear fashion, by only one thing. The tree is built one node at a time, and no other node, or object, for that matter, cares that a node is added or modified. In the evaluation phase, each node is visited and variables are added or modified in the hash table, but no object other than the current visitor from the current node cares about this. I suppose I can make each node an observer which upon observing a change does nothing, or something like that, forcing an Observer pattern, but that isn't really useful.

So, is there an obvious answer which I am completely missing? Is there a not so obvious one, but still giving an useful implementation of Observer? Can I use a half useful slightly forced Observer pattern somewhere in my algorithms, or is fully forced, completely useless way the only way to implement it? Is there a completely different way of approaching the problem which will allow me to use the Visitor and, more importantly, the Observer pattern?

**Notes:**
I am yet to implement the evaluation of the tree (steps 2, 3 and 4) with Visitor; I have only thought about how I should do it. I will implement it tomorrow and see if there is a way to use Observer somewhere, but having thought about how I could use it for a few hours, I still have no idea. I am hoping, though, that there is a way, which I haven't been able to discover but which will become clear after writing that part.
I apologize for writing so much. I couldn't summarize it better and still give details about the situation any better.
Also, I apologize if I am not clear in explanations. It is quite late, I have though about this for some hours and got tired, and I can't say I have a perfect grasp on the concepts. If anything is unclear or want further details on some matter, don't hesitate to ask. Also, don't hesitate in highlighting any mistakes or wrong paths in my judgement about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ideas how you could use well-known patterns and concepts to build an interpreter for your language:

- Start processing an input stream by splitting it up into tokens (`[;`, `=`, `x`, `0`, `]`, etc.). This first component (a.k.a. lexer, scanner, tokenizer) strips out irrelevant detail such as whitespace and produces tokens.

  You could implement this as a simple **state machine** that is fed one character at a time. It can therefore be implemented as an **observer** of the input character sequence.
- In the next stage (a.k.a. parsing) you build an abstract syntax tree (AST) from the generated tokens.

  The parser is an **observer** of the tokenizer, i.e. it gets notified of any new tokens the tokenizer produces.<sup>**(*)**</sup> It is fed one token at a time. In the case of a fairly simple grammar, the scanner itself can also be some **stack-based state machine**. (For example, if it needs to match opening and closing brackets, it needs to be able to remember what context / state it was in outside the brackets, thus it'll probably use some kind of stack for context management.)
- Once the parser has built an AST, perhaps almost all subsequent steps can be implemented using the **visitor pattern**. Every algorithm that traverses the AST, locates specific nodes or subtrees, or transforms (parts of) the AST can be modelled as a visitor. Some visitors will only model actions that do not return a value, others return a new AST node for a visited node such that a new transformed AST can be put together. For example:

  - Check whether the AST or any subtree of it describes a valid program fragment (visit a (sub-) tree, reduce it to a boolean or a list of errors).
  - Simplify / optimize the program (visit a (sub-) tree, generate a smaller or otherwise more optimal subtree, finally reassemble a new tree from the transformed subtrees).
  - Execute the AST (visit and interpret each node, execute some code accoeding to the node's meaning).

---

<sup>**(*)**</sup> Calling the parser an observer of the scanner is perhaps somewhat inaccurate. [This Software Engineering SE post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/340337/4906) has a good summary of closely related design patterns. Could be that the scanner implements a **strategy** for dealing with the tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas! Thanks for the link to the summary of the two patterns, also! Even though, as I understand, a class watching a tokenizer/scanner might not be strictly called an Observer, I guess I could make a tokenizer/scanner that will push instructions in an instruction stack, and observe the stack in itself with an Observer for parsing, that way having some actual concrete data to be observed (this, too, might qualify under Strategy, though). I am not sure how that would work out :)

Comment: Unfortunately, in the meantime the requirements of the project changed and I had to use a Decorator pattern, also slightly squeezed in the design (I decorated some nodes to make them verbose to help with debugging of the program, even if that was not actually a requirement for the program). Thank you, nonetheless, as your answer provided great insight into those patterns and into parsing ideas, and I might, at a later time, implement something similar.